# Synchronize global values between processes in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, synchronization, thread-safety

In NodeJS, I have two asynchronous functions that manipulate a single global value, here's an example:

```
var someValue = 0;

function longTask {
    // ...
    // very long process here
    // ...
    someValue += incrementValue; // modify value
    // ...
    // very long process again
    // ...
}

function shortTask {
    // get the value
    return someValue;
}
```

These two can be called anytime. (For example, I'm using Socket.io)
There's a chance that `shortTask` is called when `longTask` is still running.
What I am worried about is, when that happens, `shortTask` may get the `someValue` wrong.

Should I tweak the code to become like this?

```
var someValue = 0;
var longTaskRunning = false;

function longTask {
    longTaskRunning = true;
    // ...
    // very long process here
    // ...
    someValue += incrementValue; // modify value
    // ...
    // very long process again
    // ...
    longTaskRunning = false;
}

function shortTask {
    if (longTaskRunning) {
        setTimeout(shortTask, 500); // Delay this function
    } else {
        return someValue;
    }
}
```

I also heard that NodeJS is single-threaded.
So, is this a concern?

Comment: Are you sure you meant [processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), your code doesn't seem inter-process.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to NodeJS. I'm currently using socket.io. So, is a single socket.io event a process or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is single threaded, it use asyncronous model instead of multithreading. It's impossible that two pieces of codes run at the same time. You can run your code in several processes (what is possible in node using [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or [`cluster`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module), but in that case you global `someValue` will be unique for each process.

So in any case you don't need to concern that `longTask` and `shortTask` will be called at the same time.

**PS** See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&list=PLEebiPdGgg6nRV77RHDNe0lXAN7ya3L_3&index=7) to better understend asynchronous stuff.